# Which people or institutions own the assets of the Federal Reserve System?

Tags: federal-reserve

At [this website](https://www.swfinstitute.org/fund-rankings/central-bank), I see that the total assets of the Federal Reserve System are worth more than 8 trillion dollars. Which people or institutions own these assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These assets are owned by the [Federal Reserve System](https://www.federalreserve.gov/aboutthefed/structure-federal-reserve-system.htm) or Fed for short. Fed is an decentralized organization that consist of 12 reserve banks and the board. [The 12 reserve banks are](https://www.federalreserve.gov/aboutthefed/structure-federal-reserve-banks.htm):

1. Federal Reserve Bank of Boston
2. Federal Reserve Bank of New York
3. Federal Reserve Bank of Philadelphia
4. Federal Reserve Bank of Cleveland
5. Federal Reserve Bank of Richmond
6. Federal Reserve Bank of Atlanta
7. Federal Reserve Bank of Chicago
8. Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis
9. Federal Reserve Bank of Minneapolis
10. Federal Reserve Bank of Kansas City
11. Federal Reserve Bank of Dallas
12. Federal Reserve Bank of San Francisco

The board is in Washington D.C.

These collectively own all Fed assets.

In turn Fed is government institution, so you could say de facto those assets are owned by U.S. Government, although de jure Fed has independent and decentralized structure so I am not sure if U.S. government has legal claims to these assets, that would be question for law.se.

Comment: So if the government borrows money from the Fed, does the government actually borrow money from itself?

Comment: @Riemann yes pretty much (also I think you meant to say borrow)

Comment: Your're right; I changed it.